# ASP.NET MVC, Arvixe hosting web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, hosting, sql-server-2012

Good evening. I have a asp.net mvc3 web project, with sql server database 2012 and EF5. This site working perfectly on my local machine, but when I upload this to Arvixe web hosting and try to connect to pages which connect to database they print me an error:

```
Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required.
```

I'm try 2 different connection string, but everything without success:

```
<add name="PrimaryConnectionString"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=camellia.arvixe.com;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=false;User ID=userLogin;Password=userPassword;"/>
    <add name="SecondaryConnectionString"
connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;Persist Security Info=true;User ID=userLogin;Password=userPassword;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and in code I'm use next part of code to connect to database:

**My Context class**

```
public UniversityContext(string connectionString)
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
```

**Connect from context in project**

```
private UniversityContext context = new UniversityContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString);
```

I'll try to connect to support, but the're didn't know why isn't working, and I'm very embarrased, Have anyone ideas, because I'm in a blind alley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have the ip for the database that they gave you?

i use arvixe too, and my db conn in the web.config goes like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=65.98.21.152;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=mydatabaseLogin;Password=010101" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you use Integrated Security?